# Pseudo element manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this DOM

```
<div class="slotvideo">
  <div class="posterimage"></div>
</div>
```

I can't modify this html code but I need to add an SVG icon. This SVG is used for a function. On click I need to reach the bottom of the page. I create this CSS

```
.posterimage::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: mysvg;
}
```

Now, I can't manipulate pseudo element but I can't find another solution for doing it. How could you fix this problem?

Comment: It should be `.posterimage`, not `. posterimage`.

Comment: probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/49618941#49618941

Comment: i'm a little unclear on what your problem is.  you need to add a pseudo-element and you want to attach an event handler to the click of that pseudo element? if so, it's not possible to have event listeners on pseudo elements.  the closest you can get is to do some hacky mouse pointer detection to tell if the mouse is "over" the pseudo element when the base element is clicked.

Comment: @TNguyen if you only want to listen to a single pseudo-element mouse-events and not to its parent's ones, then you could trick it with the pointer-events rule: https://jsfiddle.net/vcxw8f5q/ But that's again closer to an hack than anything else and requires a lot of conditions for it to work...

Comment: try  `background-image: url(yourSvgPath) ` or you can just put element <svg> in the outer div, then using `position: absolute` to solve the style problem.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find what do you actually want. but about manipulating *pseudo-elements*, it's not possible. **But** there is a work-around.

You can define another class name like `.active` change the element's class to it for controlling pseudo-element.

```
.posterimage {
    /* anything... */
}

.posterimage.active::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: mysvg;
}
```

don't forget, psuedo-elements are inline by default, so if you want this background-image to show up, you need to make it `display: block` and define a set of `width` and `height` though.

and it's done. you can use that `.active` class to have controll of showing `::before` or not by *JavaScript*.